# How to make example class object using outside function and acces it from outside. Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, methods, nameerror

I have a problem or I just do not understand something at all.
I would like to make couple examples objects using outside function.
And then I would like to access them from outside.
In following code:

```
class User():
    def __init__(self,id,name,email,password):
        self.id = id 
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        print('User created.')

class Category():
    def __init__(self,id,category):
        self.id = id
        self.category = category
        print('Category created.')

class Expenditure():
    def __init__(self,id,category,price,date):
        self.id = id
        self.category = category
        self.price = price
        self.date = date
        print('Expenditure created.')

def example_data():
    """Create example data for the test database."""
    user1 = User("1", 'Daniel', 'dany@gmail.com', 'pass')
    user2 = User(id="1", name='Daniel', email='dany@gmail.com', password='pass')
    cat1 = Category(id="1", category="Food")
    cat2 = Category(id="2", category="Flat")
    expense1 =  Expenditure(id="1", category=cat1.category, price=120, date="2017-12-01")
    expense2 =  Expenditure(id="2", category=cat2.category, price=230, date="2018-11-08")

example_data()
print(user1.name)
```

After this code I have NameError:

```
print(user1.name)
NameError: name 'user1' is not defined
```

Can I make this example working somehow?

Comment: `user1` only exists within the scope of the function `example_data()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about scopes of variables. `user1` is only accessible in function block so you can't access it outside the function.

I don't know why you want to do this, but one solution is to make user1 a global variable:

```
def example_data():
    """Create example data for the test database."""
    global user1
    user1 = User("1", 'Daniel', 'dany@gmail.com', 'pass')
example_data()
print(user1.name)
```

Comment: It's recommended not to use it (unless in absolute necessity) as The use of global variables can bring problems that are difficult to track especially for beginners.